# SQLite .Net custom Build makes performance slow

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I am using SQlite in my windows application to handle a custom kind of data set.
The structure of data is obtained from another vendor and cannot be changed.

In some cases the Data needs to have a huge number of columns in the table. 
as the SQlite is having a column limit of 2000, tried of making a custom build from SQlite source code (as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221508/how-to-increase-column-limit-of-a-table-in-sqlite).)

For confirming the custom build SQLite code, we have just build the code (without any change) downloaded from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Build the project SQLite.Interop.2015 and used the DLL instead of the one we were using in our projects.

But we could find that the DB operations became exponentially slow. 
Is there anything to be taken care, while building the source code of our own?

Comment: make sure it is `release` build, not `debug`

Comment: Did you by any change produce a debug build? Anyway I'd really, strongly suggest that you find a way to map your vendor's data structure to a more sensible data structure. Needing more than a thousand columns is ... suboptimal.

Comment: @ASh It is Build in `Release` mode itself.  @CodeCaster Yes the structure is subject to change but for the time being, we have to support it temporarily.

Comment: The form you get the data from its provider doesn't have to correspond 1 to 1 with how you store it in a database. Come up with an ETL process to turn it into a sane arrangement.

Comment: @Shawn Here the output they require is an sqlite DB file, archived into a zip file. So  optimisation of DB structure is not possible unless they change the requirement.